# Error parsing data org.json.jsonException end of inpuy at character 2 of (null json)

Tags: java, php, android, json, parsing

Before I start, I have an app that I use to POST data to the server and it works perfectly. I tried to copy past the same code for use in another app and is not working, so I will explain what I did:

First, I am using `api23`, `DefaultHttpClient` is decrecated so I am using an `org.apache` library and the problem is solved.

I use that to send the data:

```
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json1 = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product, "POST", params);
```

However, this returns a null in the Log. I checked all params and they are not null. What I did was to try and find the problem in the `JSONParser()`. Everything is fine untill:

```
try {
    jObj = new JSONObject(json);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("parser", "Error trying parse data " + e.toString());
}
```

This is where `json==null` appears in the Log and it says:

> Error parsing data org.json.jsonException end of inpuy at character 2 of and that (json1) have a null reference.

I don't know what else to check. I have it working fine in the other app, using the same PHP. So I do not think PHP is not the problem because I an  using everything the same PHP.

Comment: Show your json structure